# compress-archive -update will remove an existing .zip file if the -path specification returns 0 files

Tags: powershell

Seems like this has to be a bug, doesn't it?

```
# make a tiny file
echo 'bibbity' > bibbity.txt

# this -path specification returns (at least) bibbity.txt and creates bobbity.zip
compress-archive -path bibbity.* -update -destinationpath bobbity.zip

# Now remove any such files
rm bibbity.*

# THIS path spec now returns nothing, and compress-archive actually deletes bobbity.zip!
compress-archive -path bibbity.* -update -destinationpath bobbity.zip
```

Since I specified `-update` I was expecting the existing .zip file to be undisturbed.

Comment: this seems like a bug. I think you should consider [opening an issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/issues)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon--thanks! [Done.](https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/issues/142)

Comment: I do agree with your point, as no file is found, it should be a no-op instead of file deletion. Though developers of the cmdlet might have a different opinion. I'll personally upvote your issue

Comment: Note that the repo is for Core Version of PowerShell, not Windows PowerShell version. However this issue occurs in both versions.